# Comparing Image Data Types In SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How to Compare `Image` data types?

I need compare a file stored in DB with an uploaded file But it says that comparing `Image` data type is not possible I even tried to convert to `nchar`

```
(CONVERT(char(1000), FileData)
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Don't use the `image` datatype it is deprecated.

Instead use the replacement datatype `varbinary(max)` which does not have all the limitations of `image`

In the meantime you can `cast(FileData as varbinary(max))` to allow comparisons.

Comment: @Sachin - You mean change the datatype in the table? Yes `ALTER TABLE YourTable ALTER COLUMN FileData VARBINARY(MAX) [NOT] NULL`