# Linq Select Where byte[]

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, where-clause

Actually,I'm saving a `Image` in `DB` having the `datatype` `image` by converting it into `byte[]`.
Now,I'm need to retrieve the data.
So,My Linq Query is :

```
byte[] str = (byte[])DtImages.Rows[i + 2]["COLUMN_IMAGE"];    
var dataimageid = (from xx in VDC.SURVEY_USER_IMAGES
                   where xx.IMAGE == str && xx.USERID == userid
                   select xx).FirstOrDefault();
```

> Error Message :The data types image and varbinary(max) are
>   incompatible in the equal to operator.

Is that Possible?

Comment: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/12/04/sql-server-fix-error-402-the-data-types-ntext-and-varchar-are-incompatible-in-the-equal-to-operator/

Comment: are you really trying to compare images? it is not supported in SQL.

Comment: Try reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13119691/613130 it suggests to use VARBINARY(MAX) instead of the Image data type. Then you can compare it.

Answer (score 0):

Update your Image columns as following in your mapping class

```
[Column(UpdateCheck=UpdateCheck.Never)]
public System.Data.Linq.Binary IMAGE
```

Update check should be never for ntext, text and image since SQL Server doesn't support comparison for these types.