# I really need to compare images in SQL

Tags: sql-server, image, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I know this thread: [Comparing Image Data Types In SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13119639/comparing-image-data-types-in-sql) but it isn't helpful

I'm trying to write a trigger in T-SQL (SQL Server 2008) which would check if an image of an article was changed and report it in some special table. The database uses `Image` datatype and I'm not in power to change it.

I tried:

```
ALTER TRIGGER PhotoUPDATE                               
ON ARTICLE                                      
FOR UPDATE          
AS              
DECLARE @ID numeric (18,0),@PHOTO_NEW image,@PHOTO_OLD image

SET @ID = (SELECT ID FROM inserted)
SET @PHOTO_NEW = (SELECT PHOTO FROM inserted)
SET @PHOTO_OLD = (SELECT PHOTO FROM deleted)

IF (@PHOTO_NEW<>@PHOTO_OLD)
BEGIN
 INSERT PhotoCHANGED (ID,DATE)
 VALUES(@ID,GETDATE())
END
GO
```

I get error:

> The text, ntext, and image data types are invalid for local variables.

When I tried without variables:

```
IF ((SELECT PHOTO FROM inserted)<>(SELECT PHOTO FROM deleted))
```

I got:

> Cannot use text, ntext, or image columns in the 'inserted' and 'deleted' tables.

What else could I try?

Comment: I don't know whether it's feasible in SQL server, but in Oracle, I'd compute hash values for both images (e.g. SHA1) and compare those.

Answer (score 4):

You say

> The database uses Image datatype and I'm not in power to change it.

Well in that case you can't do this then. `image` is deprecated. It is not permitted to access `image` columns in the `inserted`/`deleted` tables. Attempting to do this will cause the error

> Cannot use text, ntext, or image columns in the 'inserted' and
>   'deleted' tables.

It is possible to get the post update column value by querying the base table but there is no way to get the `DELETED.PHOTO` value to compare it with.

You will need to get the person responsible to change the column datatype to `varbinary(max)`.

```
ALTER TABLE ARTICLE ALTER COLUMN PHOTO VARBINARY(MAX) NOT NULL
```

Then you can access it inside the trigger and compare for equality.

Your trigger is broken as well. Updates can affect multiple (or zero) rows. Not always exactly one.

Also you should check  [`IF UPDATE(PHOTO)`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187326.aspx) to skip doing it if the column wasn't touched.

```
ALTER TRIGGER PhotoUPDATE
ON ARTICLE
FOR UPDATE
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF UPDATE(PHOTO)
      BEGIN
          INSERT PhotoCHANGED
                 (ID,
                  DATE)
          SELECT I.ID,
                 GETDATE()
          FROM   inserted I
                 JOIN DELETED D
                   ON I.ID = D.ID
                      AND EXISTS (SELECT I.PHOTO
                                  EXCEPT
                                  SELECT D.PHOTO)
      END
```

Comment: Thanks for bringing multiple rows issue. Actually in my case the only way this table is accessed is some application adding a single photo to article at a time so it will be one row in my case. But I'll remember it's not always. As for the images I decided to change the program functionality if it is so hard to compare them. Comparing 500 kB of bytes could dramatically slow down the database anyway.